# How to drop all of the indexes except primary keys with single query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I am planning to drop all of the indexes except the primary keys. I made the primary keys myself but all other indexes was suggestion of SQL Server.

After dropping all indexes which are not primary keys, planning to use SQL Server profiler tuning template for database tuning advisor and create indexes.

With this way planning to not have unused indexes or performance degrading indexes.

How logical is this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'DROP INDEX ' 
    + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ';'
    FROM sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS o
    ON i.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 0
AND i.index_id <> 0
AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: and 1 more thing. add char 13 for new line :D + '.' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ';'+char(13)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is probably this: run this query which will output a list of `DROP INDEX .....` statements.

```
SELECT 
   'DROP INDEX ' + name + ' ON ' + 
   OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(object_Id) 
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE is_primary_key = 0
AND name IS NOT NULL
AND OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) <> 'sys'
```

Copy those DROP statements from the results grid to a new query window, check them, maybe tweak them, and then run them to actually drop the indices.

Comment: Just a comment about trusting that all system objects are in the sys schema... if you accidentally run this code in MSDB or master, you will return rows for system objects that are not in the sys schema. Just something to keep in mind - you can correct for that easily by using `OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks - your solution definitely works even better than mine - I'll have to make a mental note of that for the future! Thanks

Comment: A problem with mine is that if the database has a LOT of indexes you might not be able to preview the entire string. But you will be able to execute it - unless it is absolutely ginormous.