# Is there a MySQL command drop all indexes except PRIMARY index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-delete

I have a database table with one Index where the keyname is PRIMARY, Type is BTREE, Unique is YES, Packed is NO, Column is ID, Cardinality is 728, and Collation is A.

I have a script that runs on page load that adds entries to the MySQL database table and also removes duplicates from the Database Table.

Below is the script section that deletes the duplicates:

```
// Removes Duplicates from the MySQL Database Table

   // Removes Duplicates from the MySQL Database Table based on 'Entry_Date' field
      mysql_query("Alter IGNORE table $TableName add unique key (Entry_Date)");

   // Deletes the added index created by the Removes Duplicates function
      mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $TableName DROP INDEX Entry_Date");
```

Using the Remove Duplicates command above, an additional index is added to the table. The next line command is suppose to delete this added index.

The problem is that sometimes the added index created by the Removes Duplicates command does not get deleted by the following Delete added index command and therefore more indexes are added to the table. These additional indexes prevent the script from adding additional data to the database until I remove the added indexes by hand.

My Question:
Is there a command or short function that I can add to the script that will delete all indexes except the original index mentioned in the beginning of this post?

I did read the following post, but I don't know if this is the correct script to use:
[How to drop all of the indexes except primary keys with single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530103/how-to-drop-all-of-the-indexes-except-primary-keys-with-single-query)

Comment: I don't this it is for MySQL. It states it's for SQL Server

Comment: Sorry @sammy, I missed that point.

Comment: Why do you constantly add and remove the unique index? You should not let those duplicates in there in the first place. Just keep the unique key and deal with errors while you insert new rows. That will be a lot more efficient.

Comment: as stated in the post the Removes Duplicates from the MySQL Database Table command: mysql_query("Alter IGNORE table $TableName add unique key (Entry_Date)"); automatically adds the additional index.

Comment: repeating what @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned: why don't you create that unique key in the database and remove the line that keep adding and removing the index. so you comment out the mysql_query() lines.

Comment: I don't quite understand. The command" mysql_query("Alter IGNORE table $TableName add unique key (Entry_Date)"); removes duplicate record rows in the table, but as a result, it also adds the additional indexes. The next command: mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $TableName DROP INDEX Entry_Date"); removes the added index most of the time, but not always. Is there a better way to remove duplicate entries in a database table?

Comment: @Sammy: again: don't let those duplicates go in there into the table in the first place by not removing the unique index.

Comment: @Sammy, you're not reading what they're saying. If you **don't let the duplicates into the DB in the first place**, you don't have to run anything to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, what you can do is create copies but that wouldn't copy the index. for example if you make
create table1 as (select * from table_2), he will make copy but without index or PK.

Comment: it is not efficient to constantly create a new table on every webpage load. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

After all the comments I think I realize what is happening.
You actually allow duplicates in the database. You just want to clean them some times.
The problem is that the method you have chosen to clean them is through creating a Unique key and using the IGNORE option which causes duplicate lines to get dropped instead of failing the unique key creation. then you drop the unique key so that duplicate rows can be added again. your problem is that sometimes the unique key is not being dropped.

I suggest you delete the duplicates in another way. supposing that your table name is "my_table" and your primary key is my_mey_column then:

```
delete from my_table where my_key_column not in (select min(my_key_column) from my_table group by Entry_Date)
```

**Edit**: the above won't work due to limitation in mysql as pointed by @a_horse_with_no_name

try the three following queries instead:

```
create temporary table if not exists tmp_posting_data select id from posting_data where 1=2 

insert into tmp_posting_data(id) select min(id) from posting_data group by Entry_Date

delete from Posting_Data where id not in (select id FROM tmp_posting_data)
```

As a final note, try to reconsider the need to allow the rows to be duplicated also as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name.  instead of allowing rows to be entered and then deleted, you can create the unique key once in the database like:

```
Alter table posting_data add unique key (Entry_Date)
```

and then, when you are inserting new data from the RSS use the following instead of "insert" use "replace" which will delete the old row if it is  a duplicate on the primary key or any unique index

```
replace into posting_data (......) values(.....)
```

Comment: A.J. I am new to MySQL. Are you saying to replace the two mysql_query lines of code mentioned in the original posting with this? mysql_query("DELETE FROM $TableName WHERE PRIMARY not in (SELECT min(PRIMARY) FROM $TableName group by Entry_Date)"); If so, would this be the correct syntax to use in my PHP script? Will this remove the duplicate entries?

Comment: yes. but PRIMARY has to be the name of the column that is the primary key of your table. by the way is this running only on one table or more ? and if on one table then what is the name of the primary key column/s ?

Comment: in the Table structure Indexes section of phpmyadmin, the primary key column is called id (Column is id). This operation is for only one table. I modified the code to read mysql_query("DELETE FROM $TableName WHERE id not in (SELECT min(id) FROM $TableName group by Entry_Date)"); Is this correct now? BTW... Thank you for all your help.

Comment: so replace PRIMARY with ID in what you have typed in the comment.

Comment: yes it looks correct to me. you can try running it not in php (but use the real table name instead of $table_name and see how it works. when you see it working you put it in the script. and you are welcome.

Comment: The delete won't work, because of MySQL's stupid limitations on sub-selects. It won't let you use the table you are deleting from in the sub-select.

Comment: I received the following error when trying it in myPHPAdmin. Code: DELETE FROM Posting_Data WHERE id not in (SELECT min(id) FROM Posting_Data group by Entry_Date); Error: 
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'Posting_Data' for update in FROM clause

Comment: just what @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned why it won't work. sammy, I guess you must use temporary tables then. did you use that before ?

Comment: yes I did read it, but keep in mind that this script runs on each webpage view. That would be too much overhead to run on each page view. Since the added indexes are Entry_Date_1, Entry_Date_2, Entry_Date_3, etc. can I use the following loop to remove the added indexes?
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $entry_date = 'Entry_Date_'.$i;
  mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $TableName DROP INDEX $entry_date");
}

Comment: do you really need to allow duplicate rows ? why are there duplicate rows in the first place ? why not do what @a_horse_with_no_name suggested and allow only one row to be inserted and ignore the duplicates ? isn't that better that inserting all the rows only to delete them later ?

Comment: The script fetches RSS content that is updated from the sources every minute or so and enters it into a database table. The script then removes the duplicates from the database table.

Comment: I can give this a try, but will using this create temp table method on every page view slow down the system if the table contains a million records?